# How to override the displayed resource URI only when the Resource is being shown as a list?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'd like to include the users name in the UserResource URI, but only when the Resource is being listed as `Full=False`.

I've tried to override `dehydrate_resource_uri` but that only applies to when view the detail view of a Resource, and I've tried overriding `get_resource_uri` but I'm not sure how to detect whether the Resource is toggled `Full` or not and the UserResource is always seen as `api_dispatch_detail` even if its being shown as a field of another Resource.

Here's an example of a GroupResource where the UserResource is nested and what I'd like to have shown

```
{
    id: 1,
    resource_uri: "/api/v2/group/1/",
    users: [
        [
            "/api/v2/user/8/",
            "First_name Last_name" #this is what I'd like to have added
        ],
        [
            "/api/v2/user/9/",
            "First_name Last_name" #this is what I'd like to have added
    ]
}
```

And then the UserResource detail page should not have the name shown:

```
{
    id: 1,
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    resource_uri: "api/v2/user/1/", #no names needed here, since I've already got their name 
}
```

The tricky part is that in a detail view on a UserResource, I don't need their first and last name shown in the `resource_uri`, although I know I can use `dehydrate_resource_uri` to remove the name from the uri before its shown to the api user. I could also check the requests path to see what resource is being looked at, but that's less than idea as it'd require a hardcoded uri.

So the question is how to show a custom URI based on whether the resource is being shown as a URI only or a fully detailed view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't accept my own answer so soon, but my current solution seems to work:

- in `get_resource_uri`, build the full uri with the names as a tuple
- in `dehydrate_resource_uri`, return only the first element in the uri tuple

  ```
  def dehydrate_resource_uri(self, bundle):
  """
  For the automatically included ``resource_uri`` field, dehydrate
  the URI for the given bundle.

  Returns empty string if no URI can be generated.
  """

  try:
      uri=  self.get_resource_uri(bundle)
      return uri[0]

  except NotImplementedError:
      return ''
  except NoReverseMatch:
      return ''
  ```

```
    def dehydrate_resource_uri(self, bundle):


        try:
            uri=  self.get_resource_uri(bundle)
            return uri[0] #return only uri

        except NotImplementedError:
            return ''
        except NoReverseMatch:
            return ''
```

I think this works so that whenever the detail view of the `UserResource` is called, the `dehydrate_resource_uri` is also called and ran, but not when just the uri itself is needed.